# C++ function parameters and classes

Tags: c++, function, class

I was just wondering if you could explain to me how functions with parameters work.
I've been following tutorials etc but they do not seem to explain how the code works to get the output. Heres an example:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;



class stan
{
public:
    void setName(string x)
    {
        name = x;
    }
    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

private:
string name;
};

int main()
{
stan con;
con.setName("Bruce Almighty");
cout << con.getName() << endl;
}
```

I do not get how we get from the public string name to the private string name. What I'm saying must sound really confusing but I don't know how else to put it, I would just like to be able to understand how this code works.
Thanks to anyone that helps, it means alot

Comment: `SetName` is assigning the string `name` for the  object `con` to Buruce Almighty and `getName` is returning back the value which is present in that string variable `name`

Comment: Which development environment are you using? You should be able to use the debugger to step through the code line by line, and inspect the values of variables as you go through each step. That really helps when learning how things work.

Comment: Did the code you posted compile? You have a using declaration for class `std::string` (`using std::string`), but you didn't include the relevant header `<string>`.

Comment: @GregHewgill I'm using Codeblocks, how would I do this?

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Yeah it does compile

Comment: @ColeSelby: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with Codeblocks. Lots of people use it though, so you should get somebody who knows how.

Answer (score 1):

1. Program starts at function `main`.
2. It declares a local variable `con` of type `stan`.
3. Method `setName` of object `con` is called with argument `"Bruce Almighty"`.
4. Method with heading `void setName(string x)` starts executing.  Parameter `x` takes the value of the corresponding argument (`"Bruce Almighty"`).
5. Private member `name` of this object is set to the value of parameter `x` (`"Bruce Almighty"`).
6. Method `setName` returns to the point it was invoked.
7. `cout` represents console output.
8. To apply operator `<<`, `con.getName()` needs to be evaluated.  Method `getName` of object `con` is called with no arguments.
9. Method with heading `string getName()` starts executing.  No parameters involved.
10. Value of private member `name` of this object is returned (`"Bruce Almighty"`).
11. Method `getName` returns to the point it was invoked with value `"Bruce Almighty"`.
12. `cout` uses this value and produces it in the console.
13. The same `cout` object produces `endl` value in the console.  `endl` make a new line to be created in the console.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

> - private members of a class are accessible only from within other
>     members of the same class or from their friends.
> - protected members are accessible from members of their same class and from their friends,
>     but also from members of their derived classes.
> - Finally, public members are accessible from anywhere where the object is visible.

Basically, a private member is something that ONLY a class function can access. So "string name" can only be read/write from class functions. Public functions/variables can be called from outside the class, the example you gave is "setName" and "getName"

So in order to write or read the private string, your code uses the public functions you created.

Answer (score 0):

Basic steps:

```
con.setName("Bruce Almighty");
```

calls the `setname` function and passes the string `"Bruce Almighty"` to it.

```
void setName(string x)
```

receives the string `"Bruce Almighty"` that you sent, and calls it `x`.

```
name = x;
```

assigns the value of `x`, which is `"Bruce Almighty"`, to the variable `name`.

```
con.getName()
```

asks for a value from the `getName` function.

```
string getName()
```

declares the `getName` function as one that returns a `string`.

```
return name;
```

takes the string held in the variable `name`, which `setName` set to `"Bruce Almighty"` and returns it to the caller, which sends it to `cout` for outputting.

Answer (score 0):

setName is somebody who helps you to deliver your string, "Bruce Almighty" to the private name field in the stan village.

You are saying, "Hey setName, I am going to pass "Bruce Almighty" argument as your parameter ***x***. I don't care how you do it, but simply deliver it to the private ***name*** field!

setName says, "Ok, I got it, you mean my ***x*** parameter is Bruce Almighty right?"

You say, "Yes right!"

setName says. "Ok, I am done. You don't need to know how I did it. This is what we call abstraction. You simply order, but you don't need to understand how I did it. However, just in case you want to know, I did it by using the assignment operator ***=***. I placed the private name field on the left side, and my parameter ***x*** on the right side. Because you provided Bruce Almighty to my parameter ***x***, it is assigned to the private ***name*** field. Boom!"

Answer (score 0):

Inside a class definition you can access data members using just their name. E.g. inside `setName` body the names of all members are in scope, thus also the private data member `name`. In this way the statement:

```
    name = x;
```

assigns the value of `x` (the argument of `setName`) to `name`, which is the private data member.

You must be careful when naming members, though, as name clashes may arise if a local variable is named the same as a member. You can avoid them either prefixing your members with `this->` like:

```
    this->name = x;
```

or using a naming convention such as giving to any data member's name a prefix:

```
    m_name = x;    // "m_" stands for "member"
...
private:
    string m_name;
```

`this` is a C++ keyword representing a pointer to the object on which you invoke your methods (i.e. member functions). It can be used to refer to that object inside a class definition. Thus `this->name` means *"the member called `name` inside the object pointed by the pointer `this`"*